# TinyMCE source code only

Tags: javascript, tinymce

How can I work with TinyMCE in source code only? TinyMCE converts any data to HTML and shows it. I need to use BBCode without converting, source code only. I couldn't find any info about it in Google.

Comment: Nothing here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration ? If you only need bbcode, then there might by simpler editors to use dan tinymce. Is that an option for your project?

Comment: then why do you need TinyMCE, simply display a `textarea`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to use TinyMCE like phpBB post form. i.e. click on **Bold** and it shows `[b]text[/b]` and not the formatted text in bold.

As far as I know, you can't do this with TinyMCE through settings. You will need to write your own functions.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "mybold",
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.addButton('mybold', {
            title : 'bold',
            image : 'img/example.gif',
            onclick : function() {
                // Add you own code to execute something on click
                ed.focus();
                ed.selection.setContent("[b]" + ed.selection.getContent() + '[/b]');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Cool for two or three codes. A pain in the ass and long code if you are going to do it for every bbcode.

If you are not going to use none of TinyMCE advantages, you are better off writing your own code to manipulate `<textarea>` and avoid loading TinyMCE JS. It would be lighter.